# best introductory intuitive books for learning ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, soft-question

I want to know best introductory intuitive books for learning ODE (mainly interested in Picard' theorem, Gronowall's inequality and most importantly stability). I started with Philip Hartman. Not finding it useful.